# materialized views creation - can be based on simple tables?

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

In Oracle, can we create materialized views in which the defining query is based on a non-partitioned table? I did not found some examples related to this..

Thanks.

Comment: that's about data warehousing.... I asked about materialized views, if they require that the query being based on a partitioned table, or not.

Comment: Gah, wrong link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm, same question though: where did you ever read that mviews require partitioning?

Comment: I've found only this: 
"A materialized view can be partitioned, and you can define a materialized view on a partitioned table."

So I understand that if we create partitioned Mviews, then we CAN define a materialized view on a partitioned table? Or we MUST do it (on a partitioned table)

Comment: I don't get it. You seem to understand the distinction between CAN and MUST very well. Why do you then have doubts when you read the quoted sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a materialized view without partitioning.

```
SQL> create materialized view test_mv as select 1 a from dual;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * from test_mv;

         A
----------
         1
```

Many data warehousing concepts like partitioning, parallelism, and materialized views often work well together.  And in the past there were cases where you needed to combine them to use either one at all.  But now they can all work independently, with a few rare exceptions.